# RadGrid localization

Tags: localization, telerik, radgrid, culture

I know that RadGrid and other RadControls have `Culture` property which is demonstrated everywhere on telerik web site. But is there a way to force all telerik controls to use

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture
```

when choosing culture for control? I really don't want to tell separately each and every control what culture should be used.

Comment: I remember looking into this at some point, and I think the answer is no. You do have to set it per control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My colleague looked everywhere in telerik docs, but it seems to be true. There is no general way to set culture for all telerik controls at one place. Using `Culture` property for each control is the only way I know of.

Comment: There is definetly no way to generally set culture in telerik controls. They confirm that in their forums. The only way is to set the properties like GroupingSettings in RadGrid or similar. They say that they will provide it in future releases, so let's wait and see.